# Drop only Nan values from a row in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which looks something like this:

```
Df
lev1    lev2   lev3    lev4   lev5   description
RD21    Nan    Nan     Nan    Nan    Oil
Nan     RD32   Nan     Nan    Nan    Oil/Canola
Nan     Nan    RD33    Nan    Nan    Oil/Canola/Wheat
Nan     Nan    RD34    Nan    Nan    Oil/Canola/Flour
Nan     Nan    Nan     RD55   Nan    Oil/Canola/Flour/Thick
ED54    Nan    Nan     Nan    Nan    Rice
Nan     ED66   Nan     Nan    Nan    Rice/White
Nan     Nan    ED88    Nan    Nan    Rice/White/Jasmine
Nan     Nan    ED89    Nan    Nan    Rice/White/Basmati
Nan     ED68   Nan     Nan    Nan    Rice/Brown
```

I want to remove all the NaN values and just keep the non Nan values, something like this:

```
DF2
code     description
RD21     Oil
RD32     Oil/Canola
RD33     Oil/Canola/Wheat
RD34     Oil/Canola/Flour
RD55     Oil/Canola/Flour/Thick
.
.
.
```

How do I do this? I tried using notna() method, but it returns a boolean value of the dataframe. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what if there are 2 non null values in one row?

Comment: Can you give a *copy-pasteable* example of your `df1` as code?

Comment: there is strictly only single non null value in the row. @SreeramTP

Comment: Is `Nan` really `NaN` or a string?

Comment: my apologies it is a a NaN value. not a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can mask by `notna()`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'l1': [np.nan, 5],
        'l2': [6, np.nan],
        'd': ['a', 'b']
     }
)

notna = df1[['l1', 'l2']].notna().values
notna_values = df1[['l1', 'l2']].values[notna]
print(notna_values)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(df1['d'])
df2['code'] = notna_values

print(df2)
```

out:

```
   d  code
0  a   6.0
1  b   5.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use stack and groupby like this to find the fist non null value,

```
df['code'] = df[['lev1', 'lev2', 'lev3', 'lev4', 'lev5']].stack().groupby(level=0).first().reindex(df.index)
```

Now, you can select the code column and description column

```
df[['code', 'description']]


   code             description
0  RD21                     Oil
1  RD32              Oil/Canola
2  RD33        Oil/Canola/Wheat
3  RD34        Oil/Canola/Flour
4  RD55  Oil/Canola/Flour/Thick
5  ED54                    Rice
6  ED66              Rice/White
7  ED88      Rice/White/Jasmine
8  ED89      Rice/White/Basmati
9  ED68              Rice/Brown
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a function over every row in `df[cols]` (the subview over problematic columns), dropping every `NaN` and taking the only one remaining.

```py
>>> cols = "lev1    lev2   lev3    lev4   lev5".split()
>>> df["code"] = df[cols].apply(lambda row: row.dropna().iloc[0])
```

You can also drop the original columns if you don't need them anymore with `drop`.

```
>>> df.drop(columns=cols, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Select columns like `lev` and replace `NaN` with "back fill". Keep the first level `lev1` and concat to your other column(s).

```
>>> pd.concat([df.filter(like='lev').bfill(axis='columns')['lev1'].rename('code'),
               df['description']], axis="columns")

   code             description
0  RD21                     Oil
1  RD32              Oil/Canola
2  RD33        Oil/Canola/Wheat
3  RD34        Oil/Canola/Flour
4  RD55  Oil/Canola/Flour/Thick
5  ED54                    Rice
6  ED66              Rice/White
7  ED88      Rice/White/Jasmine
8  ED89      Rice/White/Basmati
9  ED68              Rice/Brown
```

or using `melt`:

```
>>> df.melt('description', value_name='code') \
      .dropna().drop(columns='variable') \
      .reset_index(drop=True) \
      [['code', 'description']]

   code             description
0  RD21                     Oil
1  ED54                    Rice
2  RD32              Oil/Canola
3  ED66              Rice/White
4  ED68              Rice/Brown
5  RD33        Oil/Canola/Wheat
6  RD34        Oil/Canola/Flour
7  ED88      Rice/White/Jasmine
8  ED89      Rice/White/Basmati
9  RD55  Oil/Canola/Flour/Thick
```

Answer (score 0):

With your dataframe, I'd first make sure that `Nan` is actual `np.NaN` and not a string saying 'Nan'. Then I'd want to make sure that they're imputed as empty strings. Thus,

```
df.replace('Nan', np.nan, inplace=True)
df.fillna('', inplace=True)
```

Afterwards,

```
df['code'] = df['lev1'] + df['lev2'] + df['lev3'] + df['lev4'] + df['lev5']
```

And then `df.drop(columns=[s for s in df.columns if s.startswith('lev')], inplace=True)` to dispose of the old columns.

Note that this works only with the assumption given in OP's comment that there is one unique `code` in the five columns and the others are all `NaN`.